# Исключение возможности посещения страницы аутентифицакии после аутентификации

Tags: python, django, auth

код не прилагаю, т.к вопрос не касается какой-то определенной ошибки.
Каким образом можно бы было в Django после того, как пользователь вошел в сессию под своим акком запретить ему посещать страницу входа?
В шаблоне писать if not request.user.is_authenticated "показывать" - ну такое себе.
Хорошим вариантом бы было вообще на момент когда пользователь в сесси убрать эту страницу, ну или редирект на главную настроить.

Comment: "ну такое себе" - почему?

Comment: Tребования непонятны. Что вы хотите, чтобы происходило, если пользователь, скажем, по сохраненной ссылке пришел на страницу? Или ваш вопрос, как раз в том, что должно происходить? Уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Декоратор:

```
def authenticated_user(view_func):
    def wrapper_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_func
```

В случае с CBV можете обернуть `URLку`, или написать класс и наследоватся.